# Is there any way to automate the Azure SQL Database to auto shutdown using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

I want to run the powershell to schedule automated shutdown. That is to keep DB active for 8 hours from say 10 am to 6 pm.

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986213/stopping-sql-azure-db-when-not-in-use, it is not possible to shut down a Azure SQL Database.

Comment: You can only scale down the DB.

Comment: Do you have any other concern regarding this question?

Comment: Actually I'm implementing data warehouse, if we can't shutdown azure db then how can we automate scenario for DWH using powershell base on some condition or REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we can not stop Azure SQL Database. If you want to reduce the cost, you can reduce the size of it.

You can refer to this [article](https://jorgklein.com/2017/09/19/azure-sql-database-scheduled-autoscaling/) for scheduled autoscaling.