# Azure SQL Serverless tier never shuts down

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm experimenting with the Serverless tier in Azure SQL, but the database never "sleeps" because it seems that Azure is continually querying the database behind the scenes. I created the database via and ARM template.

The "Compute utilisation" and "App CPU Billed" charts on the database overview show  that the database is being hit regularly (even though I am not making any queries myself). The Top queries in "Query Performance Insight" are:

```
(@ip_address_value bigint,@start_ip varchar(45))SELECT top 1 @start_ip = start_ip_address_value FROM sys.database_firewall_rules_table WHERE @ip_address_value BETWEEN start_ip_address_value AND end_ip_address_value OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

and

```
(@ip_address_value bigint,@start_ip varchar(45))SELECT top 1 @start_ip = start_ip_address_value FROM sys.database_firewall_rules_table WHERE @ip_address_value BETWEEN start_ip_address_value AND end_ip_address_value AND start_ip_address_value > 0 OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Which seem to be from the firewall. Do I have to disable the firewall or delete all the rules to allow the database to "sleep"?

Comment: Could you please verify is Query Data Store or automatic tuning is turned off? They could trigger auto-resume.

Comment: Please turn off the following features also as they can trigger auto-resume: threat detection, data idcovery, auditing, data masking, Transparent data encryption, SQL Data Sync. Disconnect from SSMS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-serverless#autoresuming?wt.mc_id=MVP

Comment: Transparent data encryption is on - everything else is off (AD admin, Advanced Data Security, Automatic tuning, auditing, failover groups). I don't have the option to turn TDE off in the portal it seems.

Comment: Also, I've turned off Query store with : "ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabaseName] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF;" (using the Azure portal query editor - I've not connected with SSMS)

Comment: Based on the documentation TDE triggers auto-resume of the database. That should be the last thing to test.

Comment: I've turned off TDE with "ALTER DATABASE MyDatabaseName SET ENCRYPTION OFF" but something is still hitting the database. I can't see the queries though now as the query store is off. It's not at a completely regular interval though; e.g. 7:59AM, 8:09AM, 8:24AM, 8:31AM. The fact that it is the firewall rules table makes me think it has to be something in the server firewall that is doing this

Comment: I've created a server and database through the portal (empty) and that works, so I exported the ARM template from both and compared. The only differences in the non-working database are several items (all disabled) of type "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/advisors". These are DbParameterization, CreateIndex, DefragmentIndex, DropIndex and ForceLastGoodPlan.

Comment: Querying the connections to the database from the Portal, I get these (query editor I know, but the others I don't). Program_Name: MetricsDownloader ( DB31\WF-SpBYuHd0Mj5SoBX ),TdService ( NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM ), BackupService ( DB31\WF-SpBYuHd0Mj5SoBX ), 
NodeAgent ( NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM), NodeAgent ( NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM),  Azure SQL Query Editor, DmvCollector ( DB31\WF-SpBYuHd0Mj5SoBX)

Comment: I've added a new empty database under the same server and that works - TDE and query store on

Comment: It seems the Query Store is still enabled/running that Azure SQL Query Editor, DmvCollector ( DB31\WF-SpBYuHd0Mj5SoBX) seems related to Query Store. I would love to see if exporting the database and import it to a new one works.

Comment: @SturmUndDrang Could you please post your solution here? I am experiencing exactly the same issue. I have 3 serverless databases on the same SQL server and 2 of them are not shutting down, the last one does... I can not figure out why

Comment: The solution was that the app was calling the database on a schedule that I didn't know about. The queries didn't show in the query analyzer though, so it looked like it was the firewall rules. When I refactored to completely eliminate calls from the application the database was able to shut down

Comment: @SturmUndDrang - would you like to add this comment as an answer?

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same issue. My app is not performing any query. I can not figure out what is resuming the database

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post my case here, my app was not calling the database and I still seeing those calls as well, I figured out that it was the database backup.
I could see the queries in: Azure >> YourDatabase >> Left Menu, search for Query Performance Insights >> You will see the calls that was done to your database.

[Image showing the Menu and database query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULyK2.png)

Answer (score 0):

> If auto-pausing is enabled, but a database does not auto-pause after
> the delay period, the application or user sessions may be preventing
> auto-pausing.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/stop-azure-sql-database/ba-p/3890369

In my case it appears that SSMS being connected to the database prevented the database from Auto Pausing.